# Does one ride or drive a motorcycle?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct?

> I ride a motorcycle.
>
> I drive a motorcycle.

Comment: Do you ride or drive **a** motorcycle ? Did you look up the term *ride*? Did it give any examples? Please, include your research.

Comment: Both are correct and used in their own way. Including your own research would help here, as would including some context [which the "word-usage" tag requires].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Riding* a motorcycle is more acceptable in current usage than *driving* it, although you do drive a motorcycle while riding it. This is analogous to how people rode horses before the invention of the motorcycle, sitting on top of it (motorcycles are also called steel horses informally). With cars it is more like driving a team of horses, analogous to driving a horse carriage (cars were also called horseless carriages initially). This also has to do with the fact that you sit inside a car, rather than on top it.

[Partially inspired by [The Chicago Manual of Style Online](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Usage/faq0021.html).]

Comment: Because links can die, link-only answers are **deprecated and liable to deletion.** Please bring some of the information from the link to answer the question in your own words.

Comment: Sorry, new user. I will edit my answer.